# super slow WINDOWS 7 installation on asus p5q se plus

Tags: windows-7, installation, performance

am i missing something obvious in the bios as this is not normal at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "Slow"?

Comment: boot up, boot from cd, windows loads, blue background starts, then about 10 minutes later i have the ready to install window with the first set of options (this is the screen before you get to the part where you can partition your drives). this can't be common?

Comment: Just to update others looking for an answer, the issue is the legacy diskette support and by turning it off in the bios the issue goes away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this when I build some machines here in our office and Superuser came to the [rescue](https://superuser.com/questions/17207/windows-7-install-stuck-at-setup-is-starting).

All you have to do is disable the Legacy Floppy drive in your BIOS.

Comment: yeah looking for that setting in the bios and i don't see anything remotely close to that?

Comment: This should be in the first page of the BIOS, look at this pic: http://i.neoseeker.com/neo_image/152598/article/asus_p5b-e/main.jpg there you'll see that it says Legacy Diskette A, set it to Disabled.

Comment: That was my problem when I installed it the first time.