# How to Install Windows 7 on ASUS P5B SE without a hang or stall

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

This question is similar to [super slow WINDOWS 7 installation on asus p5q se plus](https://superuser.com/questions/150808/super-slow-windows-7-installation-on-asus-p5q-se-plus), but was not solved by that one.

The problem is that during installation of Windows 7 (Professional, x64, English) on an ASUS P5B SE motherboard there was a very long hang after displaying the background picture, but before displaying the Keyboard and Language selection dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to upgrade the BIOS from the initial version '0302' to the latest version found on the ASUS hardware web site:  http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5B_SE/#download.

Beta Version 1103, released on June 10 2009 worked for me.

- Using a USB Key formatted for the FAT filesystem, download the BIOS
  image and place it on the key.
- Insert the key into any available USB port on the target system.
- Power-on the target system, pressing `DEL` to enter the BIOS Setup program.
- Navigate to the ASUS EZ-FLASH utility.
- Select the USB drive's file named ending in .ROM.
- Apply the BIOS to the motherboard.