# How do I get the Windows 7 installer onto a USB drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb, storage, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to install Windows 7 RC from a USB disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/1603/how-to-install-windows-7-rc-from-a-usb-disk)
>   [Create pendrive installer for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/14979/create-pendrive-installer-for-windows-7)

I'm having trouble installing Windows 7 onto my old laptop.  The problem appears to be the laptop's DVD-ROM no longer seems to work. Sucks.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to get a bootable USB with my Windows 7 DVD info onto it.  I found this link here on superuser.com:

[How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

That looks good, except for the detail about making the USB bootable.  It said that the OS you're making it bootable on must be the same as the machine you're going to be installing it on.  I can't do that.  The machine I would make it bootable from is a 64-bit version of Windows 7.  The target machine is 32-bit.  So, how's this going to work?

Comment: Dupes http://superuser.com/questions/14979/create-pendrive-installer-for-windows-7 http://superuser.com/questions/93494/install-windows-7-on-usb-hard-drive-and-run-from-it http://superuser.com/questions/17880/can-i-install-windows-os-windows-7-on-a-removable-usb-hard-drive

Comment: You cannot install a 64 bit copy of Windows 7 on a processor which doesn't support x64. You will need a 32 bit installation source. However, it should work fine to create the flash drive installer while using a 64 bit installation, as long as your install source is 32 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft provides a tool for that, the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool).

you can find some instructions to help [here](http://kmwoley.com/blog/?p=345).

Worked for me pretty nice.