# Is it possible to create bootable linux on USB drive using windows command line?

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

we can create bootable windows 7 on usb drive[(here)](https://superuser.com/questions/1603/how-to-install-windows-7-rc-from-a-usb-disk/15019#15019) using windows command line, is it possible to create bootable linux using windows command line? ( i.e. not using any software)

I've entered the following commands in diskpart and copied the linuxmint files in usb falsh drive , but cannot boot from it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the command diskpart as in the link, I tried with fat32 and it works fine.

- list disk
- select disk 1
- clean
- create partition primary
- active
- format fs=fat32 quick
- assign
- exit

You can use the command

xcopy source:*.* /S/E/F destination:\

Comment: I do the command you said but cannot boot from usb!(for linnuxmint).

Comment: I tried in Ubuntu, can it be a problem with the BIOS boot or UEFI?